# How to configure an entity to save the summed value from a nested list?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two entity classes (Order, OrderItem) and one Value Object cl(Money).

Simplified code:

```
public class Order
{
    private Order()
    {
    }

    public int OrderId { get; private set; }

    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; } = new ();

    public Money TotalGrossAmount
    {
        get => new Money(OrderItems.Sum(x => x.TotalNetAmount.Amount), "USD");
        private set { }
    }

    // ...rest of code
}

public class OrderItem
{
    private OrderItem()
    {
    }

    public int OrderItemId { get; private set; }
    public Money TotalNetAmount { get; private set; }

    // ...rest of code
}

public class Money
{
    public Money(decimal amount, string currency)
    {
        Amount = amount;
        Currency = currency;
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
    public string Currency { get; private set; }
}
```

For efficiency purposes, I'd like to have the summed amount of the order items in the database in the Order table.

The Order entity is configured like this:

```
public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Order), DbSchemas.Default);
        builder.HasKey(x => x.OrderId);

        // ...rest of code

        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.TotalGrossAmount, navigationBuilder =>
        {
            navigationBuilder.Property(p => p.Amount);
            navigationBuilder.Property(p => p.Currency);
        });
    }
}
```

Migration creates the correct table structure with columns: TotalGrossAmount_Amount, TotalGrossAmount_Currency

But for this configuration, the application throws an exception:

The value of 'Order.TotalGrossAmount#Money.OrderId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.

How should I configure Order entities correctly?

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the reply. That was my mistake when posting the code on SO.
In fact, OrderItems is a property (I corrected the code).